# JMETER a ${__RandomString function that is used for creating email addresses

Tags: jmeter

I have tried:

```
${__ RandomString (qwerty,"@",".com") }
```

but it is not fine. I wonder how can I create this type of random email addresses?
I haven't added anything in the Random Variable because I am not sure that I need to use it.

Comment: i think i found it: ${__RandomString(10,qwertyuiopasra)}@mail.com

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As per [Using JMeter Functions](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743670-using-jmeter-functions---part-i) guide __RandomString() function takes 3 parameters:

1. Length of the desired random string
2. Source characters
3. If you need to store generated string into a JMeter variable you can provide variable name as 3rd argument.

So to get line of 10 alphabet characters you can use __RandomString function as follows:

```
${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}
```

Answer (score 8):

mail format:

RandomString(COUNT_OF_CHARS,LIST_OF_CHARS,) + '@' + RandomString(COUNT_OF_CHARS,LIST_OF_CHARS,) + '.' + RandomString(COUNT_OF_CHARS,LIST_OF_CHARS,)

We can specify how many characters it should contain using function ${__Random(MIN,MAX,)}

So finaly it may look like:

```
${__RandomString(${__Random(3,9,)},abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}@${__RandomString(${__Random(2,3,)},abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}.${__RandomString(${__Random(2,3,)},abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.